# Corona Near Field Comunication (NFR)

Tags: coronasdk

Does Corona SDK support NFR and if so can someone point me to a resource? 
I want a simple way to share data with another device running the same APP in close proximity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Corona now supports NFC via third-party plugins.

https://marketplace.coronalabs.com/plugin/nfc